# Parameter accept wrong type and still runs fine — why?

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

Below I have a method I search from the internet to calculate the percentrank function of Excel in C#. I modify a bit to suit my program but didn't change the main logic.

The program compiles and runs fine without any error (that I am aware of). However further checking my code, in my main, I call the function using

```
        double result = percentRank( array, x);
```

where

x is an int
array is a List (int)

It is of a different type than what percentRank method is specified to take, but it still runs fine. My question is WHY?

```
        private static double percentRank(List<int> array, double x)
        {
            //        Calculate the PERCENTRANK(array, x)
            //If X matches one of the values in the array, this function is
            //equivalent to the Excel formula =(RANK(x)-1)/(N-1) where N is the number of data points.
            //If X does not match one of the values, then the PERCENTRANK function interpolates.
            // http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/algorithm-computing-excel-percentrank-t946312.html


            array.Sort();

            double result = 0;
            bool foundX = false;

            for (int index = 0; index < array.Count; index++)
            {
                if (array[index] == x)
                {
                    result = ((double)index) / ((double)array.Count - 1);
                    foundX = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // calculate value using linear interpolation

            if (foundX == false)
            {
                double x1, x2, y1, y2;

                x1 = x2 = x;

                for (int i = 0; i < array.Count - 1; i++)
                {
                    if (array[i] < x && x < array[i + 1])
                    {
                        x1 = array[i];
                        x2 = array[i + 1];
                        foundX = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (foundX == true)
                {
                    y1 = percentRank(array, x1);
                    y2 = percentRank(array, x2);

                    result = (((x2 - x) * y1 + (x - x1) * y2)) / (x2 - x1);
                }
                else
                {
                    // use the smallest or largest value in the set which ever is closer to valueX

                    if (array[0] > x)
                    {
                        result = 0;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        result = 1;
                    }
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

EDIT: OK the answer is implicit type conversion. Can I disable it? I don't like it because it may generate some bugs that I am not aware of.

Comment: I don't really understand the question. Although your variable is called "array" it is really a list, so the function is begin called the the proper type. This seems perfectly fine, but I highly suggest you change your parameters name to something better (such as cellValueList so you know where the data comes from).

Comment: @BenjaminDangerJohnson He's asking why he can pass an `Int32` into a parameter defined as taking `Double`  ("x", not "array")

Comment: aren't you going refactor this method?

Comment: ah very good then. I thought he was confusing his list<int> as an int[] type

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> My question is WHY?

You can assign an integer to a double value.  C# will implicitly convert from `Int32` to `Double`.

You can see this here:

```
double value = 3;
```

This is allowed because of the same implicit conversion.  Without that conversion, you would have to type:

```
double value = 3.0;
```

This is specified in the C# Language Specification, section "6.1.2 Implicit numeric conversions"

> The implicit numeric conversions are:

...

> - From int to long, float, double, or decimal.

Comment: thank you, stupid question --> can i disable this implicit cast? because it may introduce error in my program that i am not aware of?

Comment: @ClaytonLeung No.  It's part of the language itself.  `Int32` is always implicitly converted to `Double` if you pass it to one.

Answer (score 2):

The C# compiler is performing an implicit cast operation.  A double can hold any integer value.

Answer (score 1):

There is an `implicit` conversion from `int` to `double`.

The conversion is implicit because a double can hold the value of an int without losing accuracy.

There is an `explicit` conversion from double to int, but no `implicit` conversion. The reason being, if you store a double in an int, there is going to be a loss of value when it cuts off the decimal places.

MSDN has a good writeup about conversions: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx

Answer (score 0):

An `int` can be implicitly cast to a `double`. That's what's happening here.